# how to redirect the user to profile page after signing up using ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello guys so basically the ajax code below checks for the username and email and makes sure that the user is repetitive and successfully inserts a record into the database. But the problem I am having is the part that says if data == true. I can't get the user to be redirected to their profile page. I mean after a user signs up, the signup form disappears and I am back to the index.php page however, it should redirect them to their profile page and signup and login buttons should disappear from my header.

```
var signupUNameBad = true;
var signupEmailBad = true;

// sign up button selected
$("#signup").submit(function(e) { 
$("#signup").css('visibility','hidden')
e.preventDefault();
if (signupUNameBad == true){
    alert("The User Name Selected is already in use, Please choose a different User Name");
    return;
}
if (signupEmailBad == true) {
    alert("The Email is already in use on the system, Please choose a different email")
    return;
}
else
// add person to DB
$.ajax({
    url: 'enterUserBasic.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'text',
    async: 'false',
    data: "fname=" + $("#Sfname").val() + "&lname="+ $("#Slname").val() + "&pass=" + $("#Spass").val() + "&uName=" + $("#signupUserName").val() + "&email=" + $("#signupEmail").val(),  
    success: function (data) { 
        // if data = true then the user was added, false the user was declined for some reason
        if (data == "true") {
            header('location: profile.php');
        }
        else if (data == "false"){
            alert("database error, please try again");
        }
    },
       error: function (data) {
           alert("Some kind of error occured in login, please try again");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: how can I do that I am new here. nevermind I figured it out. But still I got the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing PHP and JavaScript here:

```
 if (data == "true") {
     header('location: profile.php'); // PHP code will not work here
 }
```

You need to use JavaScript:

```
 if (data == "true") {
    window.location = "profile.php";
 }
```

Comment: I know that's not the best scenario, but what if you `<?php echo header('location: profile.php'); ?>;` ? Just a thought.

Comment: It won't work because you're staying client-side because of the AJAX call @William. The PHP will never be processed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks Jay but still it won't go to the profile page.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console @RaminK? Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am running this on localhost. also I watched the developer's tool and I get this app.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).foundation is not a function because I am using foundation zurb template. and about the library it is actually included otherwise rest of the codw wouldn't function properly.

Comment: You have to clear the error before all of this will work.